# How do I reduce a javascript string array to unique values but keep count of the number of duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array with a number of strings, like this one:

```js
["e", "e", "e", "e", "a", "e", "e", "a", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "o", "a", "e", "r", "e", "e", "e", "o", "e", "u"]
```

Now I want to reduce this array so it only contains unique strings. At the same time I want to keep count of the number of duplicates and (preferably) calculate a percentage that shows number of duplicates divided by the total number of strings.

I'm thinking an end result that looks something like this:

```js
[
    {
        letter: "e",
        duplicates: 16,
        percentage: 0.695652173913043
    },
    {
        letter: "a",
        duplicates: 3,
        percentage: 0.130434782608696
    },
    {
        letter: "o",
        duplicates: 2,
        percentage: 0.08695652173913
    },
    {
        letter: "r"
        duplicates: 1,
        percentage: 0.043478260869565
    },
    {
        letter: "u",
        duplicates: 1,
        percentage: 0.043478260869565
    }
]
```

How would I go about making this transformation in JavaScript/ES6?

Comment: And what have you tried for this, which looks like a school assignment in need of an answer?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: It's not a school assignment (I turn 50 soon). It's part of a linguistic experiment that I'm working on. Also it's a fun problem to solve and I thought it would be appreciated by the StackOverflow community. I knew what I had and what I wanted to get, I just needed some help getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by using [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

The reduce allows to regroup and count letters and their occurrence.
Once they've been organized properly you can then proceed to map through all the results and calculate the percentage.

```js
const data = ["e", "e", "e", "e", "a", "e", "e", "a", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "o", "a", "e", "r", "e", "e", "e", "o", "e", "u"];

const res = Array
  .from(data.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.set(cur, (acc.get(cur)||0) + 1), new Map()))
  .map(([letter, duplicates]) => ({letter, duplicates, percentage: duplicates / data.length}));
  
 console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There's quite a lot going on so I'll need some time to read it through to understand everything that's happening, but it works like a charm!

Comment: @tkahn np, if you need a more verbose version let me know. This is condenced to the max.

Comment: `Array.from` accepts a mapping argument, ie `Array.from(data.reduce(...), ([ letter, duplicates ]) => ...)` would do the same thing in half the iterations

Comment: @ThankYou thanks for the advice, however I do not believe that it halves the iterations. "More clearly, Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)
has the same result as Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg),
except that it does not create an intermediate array."

Comment: It does halve the iterations as `Array.from` takes the first pass through the Map entries, creates the intermediate array, then `Array#map` takes the second pass on the intermediate array, creating a second array. `Array.from(myMap, mappingFn)` does it all in a single pass.

Comment: Yes, applying map after Array.from does create an intermediate array but doesn't necessariy mean it's twice the iterations? Logically the Array.from  func parameter should only apply after Map has been properly transformed into an array internally.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let array = ["e", "e", "e", "e", "a", "e", "e", "a", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "o", "a", "e", "r", "e", "e", "e", "o", "e", "u"]


let result = [...new Set(array)].map(e =>({letter:e,
duplicates:array.filter(n => n===e).length,
percentage:array.filter(n => n===e).length/array.length}))


console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is also a very good solution to my problem! I see you used the spread syntax together with Set which is something I was experimenting with eventhough I didn't come so far.

Comment: @tkahn this is actually wasteful use of spread because it creates an intermediate array just to call `.map` on it, which creates _another_ array. `Array.from(new Set(array), e => ...)` is proper way to write `[...new Set(array)].map(e => ...)`